# move select2 value to other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

[image]

im using select2.
i need to move the value of selected select2 to another div
like the image
i code like this

```
    <div class="option">
    <select id="position" style="width: 100%">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="result">
    ....//the result will be here
    </div
<script>
    $("#position").select2({
    allowClear:true,
    placeholder: 'Position'
    });
</script>
```

normally if we chose the option. it went inside the button with close icon to remove what we choose. i need the value and close icon to be move to class result. how to do that? because like in the image. D-3 is the value what we choose in degree. and on the right of d-3, it have a close button that can close the result of what we chose in degree option. same like select2. can u guys teach me how to move that to inside class result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are going to do with these text result after that? if you are only looking after the design and you are not trying to append to another DIV and you still want to be able to use the plugin function to close/deselect the result, so you have to know that you will not be able to "easily" put it down because each time you point to the choice or the close button you will open the select instead. you may try to place on top.

Here is a workaround on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2t5exhv/6/) using the CSS that shows you the idea but you might need to work on it.

```
    select {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .to-bottom, .to-top {
        width:320px;
        height:200px;

    }
    .to-bottom .select2  {
        height:150px;

    }
    .to-bottom .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered{
        position:relative;
        top:40px
    }

    .to-top .select2  {
        position:relative;
        top:50px;

    }
    .to-top .select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered,
    .to-top .select2-search__field{
        position:relative;
        top:-40px
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no jsfiddle to experiment with I try to answer the question from the docs (https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#event-data)

```
$("#position").on("select2:select", function(e) {
    // make sure class 'result' only exists once or use an id
    $(".result").html(e.data.text)
});
```

I hope this works for you, otherwise more information (jsfiddle) would really help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand that last part of your question ("with the x button sir"), but here is a jsfiddle that, I believe, accomplishes what you're looking for. [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c2t5exhv/3/)

```
$(function() {
$('#options').select2({
    "placeholder": "Pick options",
    "multiple": false
  })
  .on("select2:select", function(e) {
    // mostly used event, fired to the original element when the value changes
    $(".result").html($("#options").select2("val"));
  });
});
```

Comment: in select yo the chosen come with cross button to delete what we chose right sir. i want the button too when we print inside div result.

Comment: not work sir. my button got so small after that. please help me

Comment: @vicario, please just make multiple:true in Drew example >>> http://jsfiddle.net/c2t5exhv/4/

Comment: honestly the design lis like that sir. i cant change it.

Comment: Still unclear on what you're asking as I assume English isn't your native language but, from what I can gather, I think hsobhy's answer below may be what you're looking for.